# What's the way to show the cointop 50 in webpage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{loading ? (
        <strong>Loading...</strong>
      ) : (
        <ul>
          {coins.map((coin) => (
            <li>
              {coin.name} {coin.symbol} :{" "}
              {Math.round((myMoney / coin.quotes.USD.price) * 100) / 100}
              {"   "}
              {coin.symbol}
              {" can buy!"}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
```

This is for React beignner Project,

now this source makes all coin objects return.

i already find how to use javascript statement. but can't find the way.

`coin` is using other website api(https://api.coinpaprika.com/v1/tickers)

how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily use

```js
let startIndex=0;
let endIndex=50;
let coins50 = coins.slice(startIndex, endIndex)
```

also, you must define paging to show the rest of the data
notice: you must keep data to component state

Comment: That'd be all of the coins except for the *last* 50, wouldn't it?

Comment: that was for example